# Cant get armature to move mesh!

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, actions

I am really new using blender and i am trying to get an armature to move a 3d model of a chicken that i bought.

This model has some actions that i want to use to animate the chicken but i cant get the armature tu move the mesh!

Here is my blender file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GXCgtmbWM1L0JcrP8ztB9cyZ9CjazMX7?usp=sharing

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: well it looks like your object has no Armature modifier at all, which means that no parentage has been tried on the armature...

Comment: In object mode, select object, then armature, then CTRL-P, choose with automatic weights and see what happens. Can't download your file right now cause I'm at work, but if it doesn't work, let us know.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! 
I already tried that but nothing happends when I try to move the armature in pose mode.
It's probably something easy but I just cant make it work!